# Cron won't start virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, cron

Groovy Gorilla

echo $DISPLAY
:0

I want to start virtualbox from cron and ROOT's crontab entry is:

mm hh * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/virtualbox

and I am getting this error:

```
Qt WARNING: could not connect to display 
Qt FATAL: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the
application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

what is wrong and what should I change?

started from cli works fine
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to open a user-space application from root's crontab?

Comment: excellent question! I opened it from a user but I just want to see if I can open a GUI from a root's crontab, something similar with cli commands. Do you know what is wrong with my crontab?

Comment: Years ago, root owned the GUI. No longer. Your GUI environment is owned by your username. Any process not owned by you will be refused access. What's wrong with the crontab is the owner.

Comment: As an aside, what is the goal that you're trying to accomplish here? Is there a short-lived VM that performs a specific task that you need to run every so often?

Comment: running a vpn on VM

Comment: So, you're trying to launch a specific VM at that time or just the Virtualbox itself?  Are you also trying to launch that VM when the host comes back up?